# User Management in Django

Tags: django

Recommend creating a new model.py own login and management for users? or prefer to add fields to user model that provides Django?

I wish to have a table of users with certain parameters such as ID number, date of birth, email, position held, etc. But I'm not sure whether to modify the User that provides Django or create a new model.

What do you recommend?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Django - extra fields for user form](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24945440/django-extra-fields-for-user-form)

Comment: You should check out https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/topics/auth/customizing/#extending-the-existing-user-model

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i think its better to create a Profile model where a user field field has a OneToOneField realationship with the User instance.

```
from django.conf import settings
.
.

class Profile(models.Model):
    user=models.OneToOneField(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL)#creates onetoone  relationship with the user model
    IdNo=models.PositiveIntegerField()
    email=models.EmailField()
    date_of_birth=models.DateField("DOB",help_text="YYYY-MM-DD",blank=True,null=True)
    def __unicode__(self):
        return '{} Profile'.format(self.user.username)
```

Answer (score 0):

Django's auth package is well defined and robust. I highly recommend you to use the original Django's model for User.

However, for your problem, to add an extra field in the User model, you can customize your own model by referring user to the User model with a Foreign key.